# Showing all rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project where I define a variable and I pass it to html template to recreate a PDF template.

For example I have a variable "rates" with 24 elements, **the problem is** that in html file it shows only 20 elements.

my rates variable:

```
rates = <table class='service'>
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <td>Number</td>
     <td>Causale</td>
     <td>Total (€)</td>
     </tr>
     </head>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td width='10%'>1°</td>
               <td>144.93 € for .... <br></tr>
          <tr>   
               <td width='10%'>2°</td>
               <td>144.93 € for ... <br</td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

(i only wrote 2 row, but imagine it has 24 rows)

Then I pass to my html file where I show it as:

```
<page id="page-1">
<div class="body-page">
        <div class="main-container">

            <div class="table-box payment-table">
<div class="table-box payment-table">
                    <div class="table-title">Rates</div>
                    {{rates}}
                    </div>
</div>
</page>





service: {
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body-page: {
 float: left;
 min-height: 1032px;
}
    
main-container: {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 height: 1032px;
 margin-top: -50px;
}

page{
    float: left;
    width: 210mm !important;
/*  height: 303mm;*/
    height: 296mm !important;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5mm;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

EDIT: Ok i found the hidden rows:
[image]

Comment: Are you using react?  Anyway if you just wrote 24 rows with the same (correct) style, check if you maybe have some broken tags. Maybe some <tr> or <td> tag is not correctly closed?

Comment: I'm using angular, ye i'm checking but I don't think it's the problem. If I have a number < 24 (max 18) i can see all the rows

Comment: This question needs more info so that we reproduce the bug

Comment: Yes, a SO Runnable example would be helpful, so we can see the problem

Comment: Anyway, looking from the browser console, you see all of your rows rendered? Or you just see 20 <tr> o whatever lower number? This can help to understand if can be some unclosed tag... The browser shows you the real html, so if you got all of your rows, something at style level is wrong, otherwise check again for unclosed tag, imo.

Comment: I copy and paste 24 rows ( i copied directly the variable's data, in which there are 24 rows)  but it shows me only 20. 
I have tried to copy and paste in stackbliz but it prints 24 rows :/

Comment: @Doc Ok looking elements console I see that I have 24 <tr> But only 20 are showing in the page. I have the other 4 rows in another page undercover from other text/image ( i can see the text, i see these only with the elements browser)

Comment: I insert an image with the hidden rows

Comment: Can you share this stackblitz example? Oh, sorry the stackblitz is ok, you said. My bad

Comment: Ye i'm trying, the problem is to reproduce the error in stackblitx :D anyway I found the error... it is used an html tag <page> before every page.

Answer (score -1):

Is that because you set fixed height and more than 20 elements don’t fit in the element?

Comment: I have tried to delete the max height but it doesn't change

Comment: do u see the 24 rows rendered in the html?

Comment: No i see only 20 rows, but the variable that I pass has 24 rows